# Creating a correlation matrix using novel distance function

Tags: r

I'm trying to write a function that will create a correlation matrix using a fancy distance estimate (`dcorr`, Brownian distance). More generally, I want to write code for a generic "correlation" matrix in which you can plug in any distance estimator.

My data is formatted such that columns are variables and rows are observations.

I'm having problems with my basic code. My algorithm is as follows:

- Use apply to take a variable
- Pass to function that will again take apply on the entire matrix
- At this point you should have two pairs of variables
- Use `na.omit` to remove missing observations (necessary for dcorr)
- Calculate dcorr

I was hoping this would result in the correlation matrix but I'm having a lot of problems with basic variable managment. I'm having difficulty passing variables to the apply function. In particular, I want to pass a the column that was pulled in the first apply and pass it to the second apply (that is applied on the entire original matrix)

My code:

```
dcormatrix <- function(Matrix){
  dcorhelper <- function (Col1){
    as.matrix(apply(Matrix,2,function(Col2){
      B <- na.omit(cbind(Col1,Col2))
      dcor(B[,1],B[,2],index=1)
    },Col1=Col1))
  }
 apply(Matrix,2,dcorhelper(),Matrix=Matrix)
}
```

Any ideas? I'm sure there's gotta be an easy way to do this.

Comment: Why don't you just use `dist()` to do this?

Comment: You could try inserting `browser()` into your functions and see what's going on. This will give you some insight into your variables and how they're passed around.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check out `designdist` from the `vegan` package. It allows one to define alternate distance / dissimilarity matrices. See [here](http://cc.oulu.fi/~jarioksa/softhelp/vegan/html/designdist.html).